# Import sys with reload hangs ipython inside Spyder

Tags: python, reload, spyder, sys

I'm switching development from python to Ipython (because of the decision of the developers to drop the python console in spyder starting at version 3.x). I run into a problem, I didn't have before and I'm not really sure if this is due to Ipython or to the new spyder version I'm using. When I execute this code

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('cp1252')
from foo import bar
```

where `foo.py` looks like

```
bar = 5
```

inside an Ipython shell in Spyder, the first time it executes without problems, the second time it hangs. I'm not actually looking for a solution to this, but rather would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I can't reproduce this. However, if I add a `print(bar)` at the end of your code, I can certainly do it. But I don't know why that happens, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCordoba so it's not only me. I uncommented that part of code as it is a remainder from old python 2 unicode formatting...